# How to defined a pgf function by the list of its argument/images

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to define a function with `pgf` by the list of its arguments/images.

Let me give an example. Let `$E=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9\}$` 
(in the cases I am interested in, it is always the firsts integers) and let defined  `$f: E \to  F$` such that

```
\[(f(i))_{1\leq i\leq n}=(3,7,9,-44,135,6,7645,4,9) \]
```

(here `$F=\{-44,3,7,9,135,7645\}$`)

I would like to define `$f$` as `\myfunction` with `pgf` so that I can execute the following code

```
\pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{9}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fa}{int(\myfunction{\a})}. 
The image of $\a$ by $f$ is $\fa$.
```

(I am using this to generate random questions for an exam)

I could not find something in the documentation on how to do it and I am not sure it is even possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 8 is missing ... ;-)

Comment: you are right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\foreach[count=\c] \value in {3,7,9,-44,135,6,7645,4,9}{
  \expandafter\xdef\csname myfunction\c\endcsname{\value}
}
\def\myfunction#1{\csname myfunction#1\endcsname}

\tikzset{
  declare function={
    myfunction(\a) = \myfunction{\a};
  },
}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{9}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fa}{int(myfunction(\a))}. 
The image of $\a$ by $f$ is $\fa$. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, that works perfectly for me. A subsidiary question would be where do I can learn and understand this code ? Because, right now, I am like a bad student that copy/paste a solution without understanding it :) Could you point me in  the right direction ? Best regards

Answer (score 1):

An arguably easier to understand alternative: just store the images in an array and read them out. (`pgf` starts counting at 0, so I added an entry at the 0th position.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,pgffor}
\begin{document}
\def\myimg{{0,3,7,9,-44,135,6,7645,4,9}} % zeroth entry because pgf starts counting at 0
\foreach \X in {1,...,12}
{\pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{9}\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\imga}{\myimg[\a]}
The image of $\a$ under $f$ is $f(\a)=\imga$. \par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marmot. I like your solution a lot and it is a really interesting alternative.
Indeed it is easier to understand, and it is also closer of what I had naively in mind and AFAIU it is not weaker.  But now it still means I have more things to learn than before :) Thanks to both of you for providing such solutions. I am sure they will be useful in the future for someone (at least future me in some weeks ah ah).